# Apache Cordova multiple activity

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am new to apache cordova.We are planning to build hybrid html5 application . Would like to know which is the network current user is using (3G / 2G / Wifi) . We have tried with javascript API code mentioned in apache cordova site which seems to be not working (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html). So we where looking at creating an activity does the cordova support multiple activity ? .

Regards
Aravind